# Versions of natura non saltum facit

Tags: idiom

There seem to be at least two versions of a saying sometimes attributed to Leibniz:

1. Natura non saltum facit.
2. Natura non facit saltus.

(I hope I did not commit any case errors here).  Which of them is the more fluent, and what is the effect of the inversion (placing *saltum* before *facit*) on the verbal impact of the saying?  Clarifications with respect to the subtleties of the cases used will also be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/natura-non-facit-saltus-nature-does-not-make-jumps-who-said-that

Comment: Complete account in German in  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natura_non_facit_saltus. The philosophical axiom is ancient Greek with a plural by the Eleates. Confer Zenon paradox.    Newton and Leibniz  meaning is the plural form saltus because it means continuity of movement everywhere along a mechanical point trajectory. In biology it sometimes  used in the singular, saltum, because, per se, the reproduction process is discountinous with conjectured  large single steps of fundamental changes occurring  at random very rarely and possibly a a single event .

Comment: @RolandF: Thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately my German is not up to par.  What do you mean by "Confer Zenon paradox"?

Comment: The ancient mathematics knew numbers by fractions only. So if Achilleus is trying to pass the turtle running at speed 1 by speed 100 per minute, he has to half the distance infinitely often. The Eleate Zenon from Italy conjectured that this process needs infinite time, buffling the Athenian  philosophers  with his theorem, that motion is impossible (to describe by numbers  without implied 'saltus'). The modern form is Quantum Zenon paradox; an  electron under constant recorded measurement of its position cannot move. Even the eye-brain-system interpolates movement as series of still pictures.

Comment: @RolandF, that's an interesting analysis of Zeno's paradox.  The usual version I am familiar with concludes that "motion is impossible" or "motion is an illusion", rather than that "motion is impossible without jumps".  In other words, the connection between Zeno's paradox and this *question* is a novelty to me.  Do you have any sources for this analysis of Zeno's paradox?  According to you, he did *not* prove that motion is impossible, but rather that "motion is impossible without jumps".

Comment: It is the ancient precursor of the modern two paradimata of physics: Human motion with time in space  against a momentous look at a space-time continuum  with all its history, like the gods. The incomplete Greek  mathematics, that sought absolute truth by logical proof, an therefore discarded all attempts to introduce the field of real numbers on an axiomatic basis, could produce paradoxes to common sense easily. Archimedes around 250 BC would have laughed at these discussions in old Athens: He had an idea of continuity, filling gaps between rational numbers by inifinite approximates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference here isn't actually one of *case*, but one of *number*. *Saltum* is accusative singular, a single leap, while *saltūs* is accusative plural, an arbitrary number of leaps. In other words, *natura non saltum facit* means "nature doesn't make any leap", while *natura non facit saltus* means "nature doesn't make leaps"—a very small difference in meaning.

It looks like both forms have been used historically; Leibniz didn't state it in Latin originally, and it's been translated both ways when people wanted it in a nice Latin epigram. In English, we tend to use the plural for "gnomic" (universal) statements like this, so I'd prefer "nature doesn't make *leaps*" in English. But Latin doesn't have the same preference, and both versions make sense.

As for the word order, putting the object before the verb is somewhat more common in Classical use, and putting it after is far more common in Romance. But in "standard" Latin both are acceptable, and it doesn't impact the meaning much. The most emphasized word in a Latin sentence is the *first* one, which is *natura* either way.